# How to get mplayer's volnorm working in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sound, mplayer

I recently upgraded a media-PC from 12.04 to 14.04. Now the audio-filter `-af volnorm=2:0.25` of `mplayer` does not seem to work any more. The filter is accepted by the command-line, but just doesn't dynamically adjust the volume as before. I tried to place it on different points in the filter chain, tried different values according to the man page, and verified using `-v` that it is initialized during start. Other audio filters I use in the same filter chain, like `channel` or `pan` still work, so the chain itself seems to be processed.

Is there maybe a 3rd party repository/built of a more recent version of `mplayer` I could try? Can I revert to the 12.04's `mplayer` somehow?

(I am not really interested to switch to another player that also supports dynamic volume change.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following ppa hosts a recent build of `mplayer` for Ubuntu 14.04 that has a working `volnorm` filter:

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mplayer-test

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but when I put the stats filter before the volnorm filter then the volnorm filter seems to work correctly.

```
-af stats,volnorm
```